# How to configure DFS Replication group in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, dfs

A newbie question here.

I have two Windows 2008 R2 servers. DFS Management installed. When I go to "New Replication Group", and try to create a group in the domain, I get "Insufficient Permissions", which makes sense because I am not a member of the Domain Admins.

I asked our AD admin to create a new replication group, but he created a security group in AD, which I don't think what we need because it doesn't show up in the DFS Management tool when I go to "Add Replication Groups to Display".

What are the steps to configure a DFS replication group in the domain? Is it done on some domain controller? In Active Directory? A somewhat detailed instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The guides are already written; no reason to re-write them from scratch.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc725893(v=ws.11)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dfsr/new-dfsreplicationgroup?view=win10-ps

Comment: I read that. I guess what's not clear is how to create a DFS replication group outside of the DFS Management wizard because I don't have permissions to do so.

Comment: Well, if you don’t have permission, you don’t have permission.  No guide is going to help you create it if you don’t have permissions.  What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I need to tell my AD DS admin how to create that replication group. Perhaps, that second Powershell link you sent can help.

Comment: Send 'em those links.  Honestly, as far as what rights are needed, where the tool needs to be run, etc. it all depends upon your environment, which servers are involved, what kind of namespace is used (if any).  Indeed the second link is essentially the cmdlet guide.